# inequality of $L^2$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose $g(x)=xf(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Prove \begin{eqnarray*}
||f||_1\leq \sqrt{2}(||f||_2+||g||_2).
\end{eqnarray*}

How to prove this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Similar to the argument in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/270367/46120), note that
$$|f(x)|\le\frac{|f(x)|+|g(x)|}{1+|x|}.$$